# Как я могу генерировать воксельную планету?

Tags: unity3d, procedural-generation

Я могу генерировать обычный воксельный ландшафт и использовать perlin Noise. Но как  во первых, генерировать сферу из кубов и использовать perlin Noise?

Comment: а какое соотношение размера вокселя и радиуса планеты? стороны вонселя должны быть всегда параллельны нормали к поверхности сферы или строго параллельны докгтм вокселям?

Comment: Стороны вокселя должны быть параллельны нормали к поверхности планеты

Comment: а зачем нужна именно сфера, ее откуда-то видно как сферу?

Comment: её будет видно и на ней может быть игрок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sebastian Lague](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QN39W020LqU)
. Пример того как с помощью шумов генерируют ландшафты планет на сферах. И на этом канале в принципе много интересных материалов на тему процедурных генераций.